# ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib FAILED on react-native V0.60.4

Tags: react-native, android-ndk

### **Description**：

Instruction for building from source not working: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source. The error I got as below.

### **To Reproduce**：

1.Complete instruction: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source

2.react-native run-android

### **React Native version**：

```
System:
OS: Windows _10
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Memory: 5.29 GB / 15.79 GB
Binaries:
Node: 10.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.16.0 - C:\Users\E0508417\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version 3.1.0.0 AI-173.4907809
npmPackages:
"react": "16.8.6"
"react-native": "0.60.4"
```

**Error:**

```
> Task :ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib FAILED
  make: Entering directory `C:/SVNcode/APP/RN 0.60/TestReactNativeNavigation/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/jni'
  Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.
  Android NDK: NDK_PROJECT_PATH==null.  Please explicitly set APP_BUILD_SCRIPT.
  make: Leaving directory `C:/SVNcode/APP/RN 0.60/TestReactNativeNavigation/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/jni'
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
  Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  25 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 23 up-to-date
  C:/Users/E0508417/Downloads/android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r17c/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: C:\SVNcode\APP\RN: No such file or directory
  C:/Users/E0508417/Downloads/android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r17c/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: 0.60\TestReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/Application.mk: No such file or directory
  C:/Users/E0508417/Downloads/android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r17c/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:108: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib'.
  > Process 'command 'C:\Users\E0508417\Downloads\android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r17c\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 31s
```